# java.sql.SQLException: Communication failure during handshake. Is there a server running on localhost:3306?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, servlets, jdbc

I am running servlet file in eclipse using tomcat6. When running my file it shows the following error :

> Error
>   processing resource'http://localhost/MyFirstDynaSer/SignUp...
>   java.sql.SQLException: Communication failure during handshake. Is
>   there a server running on localhost:3306?"

What would be my mistake? Could anybody help me.. This is my web.xml file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>SignUp</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>com.authentication.org.SignUp</servlet-class> 
  </servlet> 
  <servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>SignUp</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/SignUp</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping> 
  <display-name>MyFirstDynaSer</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

```
java.sql.SQLException: Communication failure during handshake. Is there a server running on localhost:3306?
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.connectionInit(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.Connection.connectionInit(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.foofy.org.DbConnection1.DbConn(DbConnection1.java:28)
    at com.authentication.org.SignUp1.doGet(SignUp1.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.serveRequest(InvokerServlet.java:404)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.doGet(InvokerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.authentication.org.SignUp1.doGet(SignUp1.java:74)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.serveRequest(InvokerServlet.java:404)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.doGet(InvokerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you add some information? What is the structure of your "servlet file" (do you mean `web.xml`?

Comment: Are you sure that the xml document the error is complaining about is really the web.xml? 

If it failed parsing the web.xml, this would not explain the following error message "java.sql.SQLException: Communication failure during handshake. Is there a server running on localhost:3306?""

Is there another xml file that stores configuration information about the database connection?

Comment: the web.xml is in the WEBCONTENT folder of my project, i am totally naive, so i cant figure out these things

Comment: When a program throws an exception, the best thing to do is to read it, completely. It shows where the exception is thrown, and why it's thrown. If you don't understand the error message, then ask about it, but don't consider it's garbage without any meaning. Post the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: i included full track trace of the exception

Comment: You have a SQLException when connecting to the database, and due to this exception, some field or variable must be null, which causes the NullPointerException later. The exception message says: *Is there a server running on localhost:3306?*. What's the answer to this question? Have you started a MySQL server on the machine where Tomcat runs? Is this server using the port 3306?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake i have done is i did not include my jar file in the Web-INf\lib folder.
and
i did not include jar file in java build path. this can be done by right click your project, click properties, select java built path, libraries tab, choose add extenal jars and select your mysql connector jar file ..hope it helps some naive like me.

ps : there is no problem in the port where mysql service is running. the port is by default 3306.

Comment: This does not explain the exception you're retrieving in any way. The stacktrace includes MySQL JDBC driver specific classes. Perhaps you had a different and outdated JDBC driver JAR file already in the classpath while you actually needed a newer version? By the way, the JAR file does **not** need to be manually added to the project's build path when you drop it straight in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Driver classes are loaded successfully by JVM, The exact problem is that you are using latest mysql server but old version of mysql connecter jar.

Recommendation:

Go to 
download mysql connectro
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html/
and download latest driver and put that to your WEB-INF/lib directory, restart the server

Good luck.